# remove quotes from colnames?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, quotes

I have a dataframe of the following form

| "column1" | "column2" |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |

How do I remove the quotation mark from the column names? I've tried using gsub but I can't quote quotation marks haha. Also need a way to do this that isn't just `names(data) <- c("column1", "column2")`. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with single-quotes in order to reference the double-quote character for replacement:

```
names(df) = gsub('"', "", names(df))
```

Test:

```r
# Set up data
d = mtcars[1:3, 1:4]
names(d)[1:2] = c('"column1"', '"column2"')

names(d)
#> [1] "\"column1\"" "\"column2\"" "disp"        "hp"

d
#>               "column1" "column2" disp  hp
#> Mazda RX4          21.0         6  160 110
#> Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0         6  160 110
#> Datsun 710         22.8         4  108  93

# Remove quotation marks from column names
names(d) = gsub('"', "", names(d))
names(d)
#> [1] "column1" "column2" "disp"    "hp"

d
#>               column1 column2 disp  hp
#> Mazda RX4        21.0       6  160 110
#> Mazda RX4 Wag    21.0       6  160 110
#> Datsun 710       22.8       4  108  93
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>